# Editing HTML in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to edit HTML in VBA and have the following code snippet:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim spanElement As HTMLSpanElement
    ' Create an HTML document object
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    ' File path to the local HTML file
    filePath = "C:\Users\Public\somedoc.htm" 

    ' Load the HTML file into the HTML document
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filePath)
        htmlDoc.write
        .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
    
    ' Find the <span> element by its ID
    Set spanElement = htmlDoc.getElementById("firstname") 
    
    ' Change the text within the <span> element
    If Not spanElement Is Nothing Then
        spanElement.innerText = "New Text"
    Else
        MsgBox "Span element not found."
    End If


End Sub
```

The html test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Template</h1>
  <p>This is a blank template for a web page.</p>
  <p class=MsoNormal>Good Morning<span id="firstname"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But on this line `Set spanElement = htmlDoc.getElementById("firstname")` I am getting a runtime error `Run-time error 424 - Object Required.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is being written to the HTMLDocument.  Make these changes:

> ```
> htmlDoc.write .ReadAll
> ```

Comment: I have never seen code written this way in VBA - a space then a "." followed by the method?

Comment: We're are passing a parameter into a method.  `.ReadAll` belongs to the file that is opened by the FileSystemObject.  See 
[Excel VBA Introduction Part 12 - With Statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmTN-nFaeOM).  That's a great series if you're interested in learning the VBA.  Thanks for accepting my answer!